# How to install Ruby Test to Sublime Text 2

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, path, ruby

I am quite new to Ubuntu, so I am running into some problems.

I was following this tutorial to install Ruby Tests for Sublime Text 2: https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests

There is one point:

> Make a copy of RubyTest.sublime-settings file to ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/ and make your changes.

But when I try to copy, I get error that there is no such folder.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like the README is incomplete, insofar as the Installation section of the instructions are cross-platform, but the Settings is Mac OSX only: the corresponding path in Linux is probably `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/`

Comment: Thank you but I found the solution myself! :)

Comment: Then please share your solution and accept it as the answer.  It will help others that are having a similar problem.